# Performing select in CustomTaskChange?

Tags: liquibase

In liquibase, I am trying to use a CustomTaskChange to perform a "complex" data migration.

The pseudo code would look like :

```
class ChangeSet031 : CustomTaskChange {
    @Throws(CustomChangeException::class)
    override fun execute(database: Database) {
       val rows = database.select("select * from mytable")
       rows.forEach { row -> 
           val content = parseJson(row.mycolumn)
           val sql = "insert into mynewtable (col1, col2) values (?, ?)"
           database.insert(sql, content.col1, content.col2)
    }
}
```

The problem is : I do not find a way to perform database.select and database.insert

At minimum, I would like to get back the underlying java.sql.Connection so that I can use pure JDBC with it

The documentation on the subject is sparse :
http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/custom_change.html

As well as examples :
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/tree/master/liquibase-core/src/test/java/liquibase/change/custom

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the ugly workaround I have finally found :

```
val conn = (database.connection as JdbcConnection).wrappedConnection
```

It works because ALL the available implementations of DatabaseConnection inherits from JdbcConnection ...